# What is the best way to deploy embedded linux application?

Tags: embedded-linux

We are developing an IoT solution with Embedded Linux. It is an application development (using C/C++) and hence we are not expecting any changes in Linux kernel/rootfs. We would like to know what is the best way to deploy our application? We are new to Embedded Linux, even though we have significant experience in RTOS like eCos, VxWorks etc. In the case of RTOS based systems, we used to depoly a monolithic image which includes everything. This could be easily upgraded via TFTP/FTP in the field. In the case of linux, we assume that we just have to upgrade the application only. When we say application, it comprises of start-up scripts, background services, processes, shell scripts etc. We know that there are different package managers (like rpm) available, but we would like to confirm that it is the right way. Of course, we don't want to reinvent the wheel by implementing our own service to perform the upgrade. Thanks in advance for the time taken to read this

Comment: FWIW, we use [opkg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opkg) as the package manager and a proprietary protocol for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Use Yocto/OpenEmbedded in conjunction with layers like [meta-swupdate](https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate) or [meta-updater](https://github.com/advancedtelematic/meta-updater). For a comparison, see [here](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/System_Update).

You can also have a look at projects like [balena](https://www.balena.io/).